# What's the point of AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm learning SQL using MySQL and I might not know certain syntax yet, but I was just wondering, what's the point of having AUTO_INCREMENT on a column if whenever I insert a new record in the table I have to specify all the other columns I am inserting each time, except the one I am auto incrementing, for example, first column is set to auto increment, now I wanna insert a record:
`INSERT INTO table(col2, col3, col4, col5...) VALUES(value2, value3, value4, value5...);`
Why would I do that if I can just not specify the columns and increment the value by myself? Why use AUTO_INCREMENT in such situation? Such as `INSERT INTO table VALUES(incremented_value, value2, value3...)` Thanks.

Comment: *Such as `INSERT INTO table VALUES(incremented_value, value2, value3...)`* Standard offers to assign NULL in such case - for AI column this means "generate next value". I.e. `INSERT INTO table VALUES(NULL, value2, value3...)`.

Comment: @Akina ok thanks, now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is important to understand that an integer column that identifies each row is very useful.  They are used for foreign key constraints and to make identification of a row "simple" (try remembering a UUID, for instance).

So then your question is "why auto increment"?  The reason is simple.  If you can have the database ensure the validity of the data, then you have a lot of advantages.  The most important advantage involves race conditions -- multiple threads that are inserting into the table at the same time.

Because the database guarantees that the values are unique and increasing, *you* -- the user of the database -- don't have to worry about duplicates.  The folks who wrote the database have already done that for you.

Comment: This is blatantly incorrect in how disparate ideas are mixed into one. Auto increment (or sequences, or whatever else) have nothing to do with validity of data, they are QoL tools for simple cases.Uniqueness of a column is checked by a separate independent routine. Auto increments also don't provide guarantees, client input always takes priority.

Answer (score 1):

You want every row to have a unique primary key and in many instances there need not be any semantics associated with that key (an example of a primary key that does have semantics, i.e. meaning, associated with it would be a person's Social Security number). In these instances a simple integer suffices as the primary key.

So clearly when you insert the next row into such a table, you want to make sure that the integer value you use for the primary key is one that doesn't exist in the table already. An AUTO_INCREMENT primary key column thus removes you of the burden of keeping track of what values have already been used.

Now you may need to know what the actual value that was used as the primary key for that last insertion was since it may be needed for a subsequent insertion into a related table where that key value is a foreign key. Obtaining the value of column that uses AUTO_INCREMENT after an INSERT statement can be achieved if you issue the following query immediately following the INSERT:

```
SELECT LAST_ID();
```

Of course, if the reason for obtaining this value is for inserting it into another table as a foreign key, then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO some_other_table(primary_key, foreign_key) VALUES('primary-key-value', LAST_ID());
```